# Azure VM - Get ClientName Environment variable

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-vm

Is there a way to get the ClientName environment variable in Azure VM. Running the below command in powershell returns correct machine name in Citrix or a normal VM but running it on a azure VM return null. Is there a way to find out the machine name from which we are connecting to azure VM.

```
echo $Env:clientname
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal VM"? That environment-variable doesn't appear on any of my "normal" VMs in VirtualBox, VirtualPC, QEmu, etc.

Comment: That environment variable holds the name of the machine from which we are connecting to the VM . Just want to know if there is a way to access the same information in azure VM

Comment: That's a Microsoft Remote Desktop feature, nothing to do with VMs.